# Recommendation/reference letter request

Tags: reference-request

I am planning to apply for The World Academy of Sciences (TWAS) scholarship and applicants are encouraged to have a recommendation letter from members of the TWAS. Is it ok to ask someone who is not personally familiar with my work?

Comment: Your question similar to this one: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75318/would-it-be-rude-to-ask-a-famous-professor-who-doesnt-know-me-personally-for-a

Answer (score 3):

There's no law that says you can't ask but it's pretty unlikely they'll agree to write the letter and, even if they did, it's unlikely it would help you.